# The column name is not valid - error

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am getting this error while I am fetching value from resultset.

> Error : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name company.short_name is not valid

CASE 1 :

```
select company.short_Name,location_name from company,location;
```

this query is executing fine on SQL Server but in my java code when I trying to retrieve value like `resultset.getString("company.short_name");` that time this give the above error.

CASE 2 :

```
select company.short_Name short_name,location_name from company,location;
```

and retrieve value like `resultset.getString("short_name");` than it work fine with both database MySQL and MSSQL.

I am migrating my database from MySQL to MSSQL.above case 1 is work fine in MySQL, but why it is not work in MSSQL?

Comment: Is the MSSQL collation case-sensitive?

Comment: It is not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`resultset.getString("company.short_name");` is wrong here. No need to specifying fully qualified name while trying to fetch the data in your application. Just specify the column name like `resultset.getString("short_name");`.

Cause even though you say `select company.short_Name ...` query out the column name as `short_Name` since that's what defined in table schema.

In case both tables has same column which may result in ambiguity, give a alias name to the columns like

```
select company.short_Name as company_shortname,
       location.short_Name as location_shortname,
location.location_name from company,location;
```

Comment: what about if short_name column also available in location table ?. it will give ambiguous error. so table name is need to define.

Comment: In that case, define a alias name for the columns. both table may have same columns but it depends on whether you are selecting them or not.

Comment: yes that is i know which i said in my question case 2 part but that i need to do in all classes of my application.so is there any solution which can we configure in MSSQL ?

Comment: There no such config setting. While you are writing the query make sure to fully qualify the column name with table name and provide column alias. See edit in answer.

Comment: @MitulChauhan Retrieval by table.columnname doesn't work because the JDBC specification says retrieval should be done by column label (which is either the alias - if specified -, or the column name), if the MySQL driver does allow this, then that is non-standard behavior.

Comment: @MitulChauhan, consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: yes thank you again mark and rahul for make my concept more clear.

Answer (score 3):

add the following to your application.properties file
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Comment: Swapnil - Thanks a lot. Its working fine for me. +1

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
select company.short_Name,location_name from company,location;
```

This query outs the column name short_Name and resultSet would also have short_Name

since the company.short_name doesnt exist you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

the function `resultset.getString(String columnLabel)`

Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.

Parameters:

columnLabel the label for the column specified with the SQL AS clause. If the SQL AS clause was not specified, then the label is the name of the column

Returns:

the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is null
Throws:
SQLException - if the columnLabel is not valid; if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set

in the function `resultset.getString(String columnLabel)`, the `arg` is a column name for executing sql,  the statement `select company.short_Name,location_name from company,location;` will get a result set, which has table headers `short_Name,location_name`